# Pandas dataframe vectorized bucketing/aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

### The Task

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| date | money_spent ($) | meals_eaten | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 10:00:00 | 350 | 5 | 140 |
| 2021-01-02 18:00:00 | 250 | 2 | 170 |
| 2021-01-03 12:10:00 | 200 | 3 | 160 |
| 2021-01-04 19:40:00 | 100 | 1 | 150 |

I want to discretize this so that it "cuts" the rows every `$X`. I want to know some statistics on how much is being done for every `$X` i spend.

So if I were to use `$500` as a threshold, the first two rows would fall in the first cut, and I could aggregate the remaining columns as follows:

- first `date` of the cut
- average `meals_eaten`
- minimum `weight`
- maximum `weight`

So the final table would be two rows like this:

| date | cumulative_spent ($) | meals_eaten | min_weight | max_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 10:00:00 | 600 | 3.5 | 140 | 170 |
| 2021-01-03 12:10:00 | 300 | 2 | 150 | 160 |

---

### My Approach:

My first instinct is to calculate the [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) of the `money_spent` (assume the data is sorted by date), then I use [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to basically make a new column, we call it `spent_bin`, that determines each row's bin.

**Note:** In this toy example, `spent_bin` would basically be: `[0,500]` for the first two rows and `(500-1000]` for the last two.

Then it's fairly simple, I do a groupby `spent_bin` then aggregate as follows:

```
.agg({
    'date':'first', 
    'meals_eaten':'mean', 
    'returns': ['min', 'max']
})
```

---

### What I've Tried

```
import pandas as pd


rows = [
{"date":"2021-01-01 10:00:00","money_spent":350, "meals_eaten":5, "weight":140},
{"date":"2021-01-02 18:00:00","money_spent":250, "meals_eaten":2, "weight":170},
{"date":"2021-01-03 12:10:00","money_spent":200, "meals_eaten":3, "weight":160},
{"date":"2021-01-05 22:07:00","money_spent":100, "meals_eaten":1, "weight":150}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['cum_spent'] = df.money_spent.cumsum()

print(df)
print(pd.cut(df.cum_spent, 500))
```

For some reason, I can't get the `cut` step to work. Here is my [toy code](https://trinket.io/python3/94046a6282) from above. The labels are not cleanly `[0-500], (500,1000]` for some reason. Honestly I'd settle for `[350,500],(500-800]` (this is what the actual cum sum values are at the edges of the cuts), but I can't even get that to work even though I'm doing the exact same as the documentation example. Any help with this?

---

#### Caveats and Difficulties:

It's pretty easy to write this in a for loop of course, just do a `while cum_spent < 500:`. The problem is I have millions of rows in my actual dataset, it currently takes me 20 minutes to process a single df this way.

There's also a minor issue that sometimes rows will break the interval. When that happens, I want that last row included. This problem is in the toy example where row #2 actually ends at $600 not $500. But it is *the first row that ends at or surpasses $500*, so I'm including it in the first bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customized function to achieve the `cumsum` with reset limitation

```
df['new'] = cumli(df['money_spent ($)'].values,500)
out = df.groupby(df.new.iloc[::-1].cumsum()).agg(
    date = ('date','first'),
    meals_eaten = ('meals_eaten','mean'),
    min_weight = ('weight','min'),
    max_weight = ('weight','max')).sort_index(ascending=False)
Out[81]: 
            date  meals_eaten  min_weight  max_weight
new                                                  
1    2021-01-01           3.5         140         170
0    2021-01-03           2.0         150         160
```

---

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def cumli(x, lim):
    total = 0
    result = []
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        check = 0
        total += y
        if total >= lim:
            total = 0
            check = 1
        result.append(check)
    return result
```

Comment: So ideally i would like using pandas' built in code, but I will use this if `@njit` (which i just learned about) can vectorize the bucketization. I just can't get this to work in my real codebase. Do you mind explaining the `cumli` function?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees sum the value until hit the limit , the total will reset to 0 and start over count

Comment: Ok this reduced my run time from 26 minutes to 6 seconds. Amazing. I think a huge part of it is because of `njit`. Great resource to learn about

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees yelp, usually the numba is faster than the simple python solution and pandas apply